# Which gem is better to use for weather feed in rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby 2.0 + rails 4.0

I want to show weather-feed on the public site, is there any gem which will show the weather according to the city name ?

without any registrations and charges.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why? write your using [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and [yahoo weather api](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)!

it is quite a way try to do something myself and know more than using someone else's

For example:

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

link = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2123260&u=c" #2123260 this code of my city
data = Nokogiri::XML(open(link))
data.xpath("//item//yweather:condition")[0].to_s
#=> "<yweather:condition text=\"Cloudy\" code=\"26\" temp=\"-6\" date=\"Tue, 10 Dec 2013 3:30 pm MSK\"/>"
```

And more pictures available weather schedule for the week and so on. Just take it!

That's all

Comment: i want to show weather-feed at public site by city_name ? in yahoo it is depends on some city_code?

Comment: yahoo depends `WOEID` code, so you can search your `WOEID city code` on this resource [WOEID](http://woeid.factormystic.net/)

Comment: can't we do without any WOEID city code ?ex : if i will pass city_name  weather-feed and it should come for that particular city.

Comment: and you can write code without a computer? strange desire to do something without putting effort.

Comment: Because i have 15000+ cities in my database and public page is displaying different city.for this some other way for showing weather-feed according to city_name.

Comment: Think how you can do it. It is very easy.

Comment: Thanks for scolding me.I can

Comment: confirm the answer if I helped you! Happy coding!